# ModelStateDictionary cyclic dependency - ninject won't self bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I created a starter MVC 3 application setup ninject and passed a controller constructor a ModelStateDictionary object in the constructor. This is the object from the System.Web.Mvc namespace.

> Error activating ModelStateDictionary using implicit self-binding of
>   ModelStateDictionary A cyclical dependency was detected between the
>   constructors of two services.
>
> Activation path: 3) Injection of dependency ModelStateDictionary into
>   parameter dictionary of constructor of type ModelStateDictionary 2)
>   Injection of dependency ModelStateDictionary into parameter modelDict
>   of constructor of type HomeController 1) Request for HomeController

How can I resolve this problem? How do I abstract it in such a way that it works? Is it possible? I've done some searching on Stackoverflow and ninject.org ... but don't see how it applies here because I can't modify ModelStateDictionary directly.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ModelStateDictionary _modelDict;

    public HomeController(ModelStateDictionary modelDict)
    {
        _modelDict = modelDict;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
}


public void SetupDependencyInjection()
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

    //kernel.Bind<>().To<>();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}


public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IResolutionRoot kernel)
    {
        _resolutionRoot = kernel;
    }


    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _resolutionRoot.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _resolutionRoot.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
}
```

This is a simple example and I am not using this way in my own code ... but the situation and the theory is the same. The ModelStateDictionary should be implicitly self bound. Ninject chooses the constructor that accepts a ModelStateDictionary object even though there is a constructor that accepts no parameters. Shouldn't ninject fall back to the constructor without parameters if the constructor with the most parameters doesn't work?

Comment: Kevin Donde,

Why do you pass the ModelStateDictionary as parameter for the Controller. I think it is bad idea. What do you want to modify ModelStateDictionary directly?

Answer (score 3):

No, Ninject won't try the constructors until it finds one that doesn't fail. It selects the constructor with the most parameters it has the a binding for and uses it. If the constructor fails then an exception is thrown.